# Como puedo asignarle color al borde de un Spinner [Android]

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Estoy realizando una validación de un formulario, y quiero que se mostrar un borde de color X en un spinner.

El problema no es la validación, lo que quiero es asignarle un color al borde del spinner

Esto es posible?

Answer (score 0):

si claro que es posible...

**Spinner**

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/tu_id"
style="@style/spinner_style" />
```

**Styile**

```
 <style name="spinner_style">
      <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
      <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:popupBackground">#DFFFFFFF</item>
 </style>
```

**gradient_spinner.xml** (en la carpeta drawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#B3BBCC" android:startColor="#E8EBEF" android:type="linear" />

                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />

                <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
            </shape></item>
        <item ><bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" android:src="@drawable/spinner_arrow" />
        </item>
    </layer-list></item>
```

P.D: @drawable/spinner arrow es la imagen de la esquina inferior derecha.